# Explanation of if statement in jQuery while working with JSON

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I am learning jQuery from book "Learning jQuery", and found part of code that don't understand.

There is part of JSON:

```
[
    {
        "term": "BACCHUS",
        "part": "n.",
        "definition": "A convenient deity invented by the...",
        "quote": [
            "Is public worship, then, a sin,",
            "That for devotions paid to Bacchus",
            "The lictors dare to run us in,",
            "And resolutely thump and whack us?"
        ],
        "author": "Jorace"
    },
    {
        "term": "BACKBITE",
        "part": "v.t.",
        "definition": "To speak of a man as you find him when..."
    },
    {
        "term": "BEARD",
        "part": "n.",
        "definition": "The hair that is commonly cut off by..."
    },
```

Here is jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#letter-b a').click(function() {
        $.getJSON('b.json', function(data) {
            $('#dictionary').empty();
            $.each(data, function(entryIndex, entry) {
                var html = '<div class="entry">';
                html += '<h3 class="term">' + entry['term'] + '</h3>';
                html += '<div class="part">' + entry['part'] + '</div>';
                html += '<div class="definition">';
                html += entry['definition'];
                if (entry['quote']) {
                    html += '<div class="quote">';
                    $.each(entry['quote'], function(lineIndex, line) {
                        html += '<div class="quote-line">' + line + '</div>';
```

Can someone explain me meaning of this line:

```
if (entry['quote'])
```

P.S. I tried to search stackoverflow and Google but couldn't found explanation for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All if(entry['quote']) is doing is checking to see if this key exists in the entry structure.

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON structure has an optional key `quote`.

If the key exists, `entry['key']` evaluates to true in a boolean context (`if`). If it does not exist, it evaluates to false, and the subsequent if-block is not executed.

So, to summarise:

```
if (entry['quote']) {        // This block will only run if the JSON contains
                             //  a key "quote"
    html += '<div class="quote">';
```

If you're not sure about the value of a variable in a boolean context, convert it to a boolean using a double exclamation mark (double negation):

```
alert("Quote exists? True or false: " + !!entry["quote"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`entry` is just the second argument in the anonymous function referenced by `$.each`. The ['quote'] part is bracket notation for referencing that particular property (i.e., the *key*), which in this case appears to be

```
"quote": [
"Is public worship, then, a sin,",
"That for devotions paid to Bacchus",
"The lictors dare to run us in,",
"And resolutely thump and whack us?"]
```